# User-provided fields not returned upon parse-login

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

I'm using the `Parse REST API` to login to my app (using the endpoint: https://api.parse.com/1/login). According to the docs, I should, when I login receive all the user-provided fields, in other words, the custom fields for my User-object.

From Parse Docs:

> The response body is a JSON object containing **all the user-provided
>   fields** except password. It also contains the createdAt, updatedAt, objectId, and sessionToken fields.

But I only receive the following:

```
{createdAt: "2015-01-28T20:21:23.554Z", objectId: "6Wg0lOKCww", sessionToken: "Mvgr5knHqnTfqlI6KqJBLSxBr", updatedAt: "2015-01-28T20:21:23.554Z", username: "testuser"}
```

Am I doing something wrong or understanding something wrong? I would rather not have to query the Parse-server for additional data.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: As far as I can remember; no. I think I had to query for additional data, but not 100% sure, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was a bug in their system at the time, but it seems to work as intended now. Custom user fields are returned upon login (if they are not null/undefined).